# Make All Columns in HTML Table Editable Except One

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, contenteditable

I have an HTML table that has an edit button. When the edit button is clicked, it allows the row to become editable. Right now the entire row is editable, however, I am wanting the MR_ID row to NOT BE EDITABLE. How can I do this? I tried something in my code but it doesn't seem to be working.

If I need to provide any more code, please let me know and I will do so.

This is the beginning of my if statement where I believe the problem should be:

```
  $(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
   if($this.id != '.mr_id'){
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
   }
}
```

HTML/PHP for the table:

```
<?php
/* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>">
        <td class="mr_id" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" id="mr_name-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" name="field" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" id="buy_id<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" id="poc_n-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" id="poc_e-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" id="poc_p-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: what is `$this`.  If it is a jquery object, then you can't get id by doing `.id` also looks like you compare against a class, should it not be just `'mr_id'` (with no leading dot)

Comment: I added some extra code to the javascript to help you out with what `$this` is

Comment: When you click edit, are you wanting every `td` but `mr_id` to be editable?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend your filter to not include the `mr_id` column:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  var tds = $this.closest('tr').children().filter(function() {
    var $thisTd = $(this);
    return $thisTd.find('.edit').length === 0 && !$thisTd.hasClass('mr_id');
  });

  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
    tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, there's no need to do all that. A simple `.not` is a lot cleaner

Comment: @jmcgriz, he is already using a filter - may as well extend it - your tds are including the .edit column as well

Comment: I was just building onto what he already has, not replacing it. I'll edit for clarity

Answer (score 2):

You can put that right into your initial find statement.

```
var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function () {
  return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
})
```

Another option, if the edit cell is always last, is to bundle that into the `not` statement

```
var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id, :last-child')
```